# Sequencial Workflow Question

Tags: workflow-foundation

My workflow is hosted in Windows Forms application. At some point I need to wait for manager approval. The manager should not use windows worms app to approve/reject the task. I was thinking about using WebService, but then I would be forced to host my workflow in asp web service.

How can I wait for the manager approval which would come from different machine?

Kind Regards 
PK

Answer (score 1):

The manager is going to have to use some UI to approve/reject the items. A web service wouldn't have a UI. You could write a separate windows forms app for managers to use, and send them email notifications about pending items.

Or, if the option is available, create an intranet website for the manager to use without having to install any app.